# Get homepage of a website of selected languge in Wordpress + Polylang

Tags: php, wordpress, polylang

In my Wordpress + Polylang website, `accueil` is the page name of homepage in French and `inicio` is the page name of homepage in Spanish.

So the homepages are:

```
English : https://www.example.com
French  : https://www.example.com/fr/accueil/
Spanish : https://www.example.com/es/inicio/
```

Is it possible to get the homepage url of a selected language?

I use `home_url()` to get the homepage.

And I use `pll_current_language()` polylang function to get the selected polylang language code of the website.

But `home_url()` returns same English homepage url even if I select any other language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `pll_home_url()` as for [docs](http://hookr.io/functions/pll_home_url/).
It accepts an argument (the language for the desired homepage).

> ```
> (string) pll_home_url(  $lang = '' );
> ```